# Number of checkins returned by API endpoints differ for the same user

Tags: api, foursquare

Recently, we've noticed that number of checkins returned by GET /users/self field checkins.count and number of checkins returned by GET /users/checkins/self is very often off by at least 10%. It used to be consistent but one the recent release has regressed the functionality. Please advice if you see the same and what's the best way of getting accurate number of checkins.

Thank you in advance

Pawel